# What does this mean?

Tags: kernel, openelec

I installed OpenELEC 6.0.1 on my Micro SD card and inserted it into my Raspberry Pi 2 B. The Pi flashes the green light 2 times and then goes off (seems normal), and then a rainbow screen appears and stays there, and the image even seems to be a little "liney" and pushed to the left, even though other images show it normal or pushed to the right. It seems the files are fine. If i try to upload my image into mediafire, i get a pollup error...

No, i don't mean that i want to fix this. I want to fix this **and** know what the hell my Raspberry Pi 2 B+ is doing and what does this mean.

EDIT: I just downloaded the wrong image, oops.

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE! IT DOESN'T EVEN ADDRESS THE ISSUE THERE!

Comment: @goobering Close.

Comment: You do have the Pi2 version of OpenELEC?

Comment: A *full-screen* Rainbow (it is actually a 2x2 image that is scaled up to fill the screen by the GPU part of the RPi - and it is the same GPU on all the RPis!) is normally only seen during the start up and disappears after the CPU has reached some stage in its process - I guess a part where it can start to tell the GPU to do something - and yours does not seem to be getting that far.  Are you using NOOBS by the way?

Comment: Creating a thread  with the topic of "What does this mean?" is a very poor named for a topic.

Comment: @Milliways Oh, i get it, i thought the download links were for all Pi's, and i downloaded accidentally the original raspberry pi version.

Comment: Hello StarOS, please let us all try to stay calm here and [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). Shouting "it is not a dupe" does not make it so. If you do not consider the linked dupe as such, try to outline the differences better. Take a step back and read your question&answer assuming no further knowledge - could a third party understand it? With the current edit history I find it hard to get the question.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, found it. I accidentally installed the Raspberry Pi version, not the Raspberry Pi 2 version. I don't know what it's doing, but it probably is doing a kernel panic or something that it doesn't understand.

Comment: You say this is about the Pi 2 version but you have a B+, which is a **model 1.**   So which is it?  If you have a quad core pi it is a Pi 2.  If not but it looks the same, it is a B+.

Comment: @goldilocks Oh wait, it's a B.